# Having trouble with a recursion algo

Tags: php, data-structures, recursion

Okay here is my recursion algo:

```
public function getCategoryTree($tree,$return = array()) {
    foreach ($tree->children as $child) {
      if (count($child->children) > 0 )
        $return[$tree->name] = $this->getCategoryTree($child, $return);
      else
        $return[] = $child->name;
    } 
    return $return;
  }
```

Here is a snippet of the data structure I'm trying to traverse

```
Object(stdClass)#290 (6) {
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["parent_id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Root"
      ["position"]=>
      int(0)
      ["level"]=>
      int(0)
      ["children"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#571 (7) {
          ["category_id"]=>
          int(2)
          ["parent_id"]=>
          int(1)
          ["name"]=>
          string(18) "Root MySite.com"
          ["is_active"]=>
          int(0)
          ["position"]=>
          int(0)
          ["level"]=>
          int(1)
          ["children"]=>
          array(11) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#570 (7) {
              ["category_id"]=>
              int(15)
              ["parent_id"]=>
              int(2)
              ["name"]=>
              string(9) "Widgets"
              ["is_active"]=>
              int(1)
              ["position"]=>
              int(68)
              ["level"]=>
              int(2)
              ["children"]=>
              array(19) {
                [0]=>
                object(stdClass)#566 (7) {
                  ["category_id"]=>
                  int(24)
                  ["parent_id"]=>
                  int(15)
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(16) "Blue widgets"
                  ["is_active"]=>
                  int(1)
                  ["position"]=>
                  int(68)
                  ["level"]=>
                  int(3)
                  ["children"]=>
                  array(0) {
                  }
                }

<snip....>
```

I'm trying to get a php data structure like such

```
categories = array( "Root" =>
                  array("Root MySite.com" =>
                    array( "Widgets" =>
                         // final element is NOT an array
                         array ("Blue Widgets", "Purple Widgets" ...) 
                    )
                  )
              )
```

I can't quite seem to get the data structure i'm looking for using my recursive algo. Any help
 would be great.

Eventually I'll need to parse it again on the frontend and display it, but another problem for another day...

Comment: When did it become "cool" to use *algo*?

Comment: sometime in the last 2 years when the word 'epic' became popular

Comment: It is not clear to me "I'm trying to store it in Mongo DB as such". So you need a way to convert your object to a string??? objects can be saved as strings when they are serialized. There are many ways in php to do this. The two most significant are: [json-encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) and [serialize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php)

Comment: luis I edited for clarity, the mongo db part is irrelevant, just need to the proper php data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ab9-wni) for a full working example. The only error I found was the `$this->getCategoryTree` which gave me an **Fatal Error** `Using $this when not in object context`. So are you sure the function is within the correct scope?

**Updated**

I hope this one works. :)

```
function traverse($root, $return = array()) {
    $return[$root->name] = array();
    foreach ($root->children as $child) {
        if (count($child->children) > 0) {
            traverse($child, &$return[$root->name]);
        }else {
            array_push(&$return[$root->name], $child->name);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Array ( [Root] => 
    Array ( 
        [Root MySite.com] => 
            Array ( 
                [Widgets] => Array ( [0] => Blue Widget [1] => Purple Widget) 
                [Gizmos] => Array ( [0] => Blue Gizmos [1] => Purple Gizmos) 
            ) 
        [FooBar.com] => 
            Array ( 
                [Widgets] => Array ( [0] => Blue Widget [1] => Purple Widget) 
                [Gizmos] => Array ( [0] => Blue Gizmos [1] => Purple Gizmos) 
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

Again, [full working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ab9-wni)

Comment: +1 for your working fiddle, but [array_push](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) is just the same that `[]`, so the question is again to @bonez, what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Finally understood what you meant. Yeah, the only error I found when using his function was the use `$this` outside of context. I've edited  my answer, it fits more like an comment now, but I'll let it be.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nf6-nby The problem is this doesn't work for multiple Level 1 categories, the first set will get overwritten. I would have mentioned that before but I just realized the issue. Please the see phpfiddle for an example. Thanks guys.

Comment: I've updated the answer (links and code). It now produces this `Array ( [Root] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Root MySite.com] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Blue Widget [1] => Purple Widget ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [FooBar.com] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Blue Gizmos [1] => Purple Gizmos ) ) ) ) )`.

Comment: In this example you've lost the key name 'Widgets' and 'Gizmos' .. THats why i've been messing with this for a while, can't see to get it quite right :) ... Also FooBar.com is should be the keyname of the Root Mysite[1] array , no?

Comment: Those weren't there in the original answer either. But I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Lets try again. Lets see if this fits your needs. NB, the working one is the `traverse` function.